# Where can I find the main query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using sql server management studio.

I closed the main query (In sql server management studio) where wrote all the tables and every thing.

Where can i find it? Under what catagory in the database?
I think I searched in all of them and didn't find. Is there an other way to find it?

Ty.

Comment: New query = `ctrl + N` ?

Comment: @christiandev
i'm looking for a query a already wrote (with all the tables creation), i lost it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you saved the query it will be on your local station somewhere with a .sql file extension. I think the default location would be C:\Users\\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Projects. As Lmu92 points out if you did not save the query it is probably gone.

If you ran the query against the database and have not restarted the SQL instance you may be able to recover it from the cache with this query.

```
SELECT      deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time],
            dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY    deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you mean by "wrote all the tables and every thing".

If you closed the query window without saving the query (either using SSMS "Save AS..." functionality or saved it using CREATE PROCEDURE or CREATE VIEW) then the query is lost.
Except you have a profiler trace running to capture the latest queries or any SSMS add-on in place that'll save the content of the SSMS query window.

SSMS is not really part of the database. It's a GUI that makes it easier to work with SQL Server. Nothing more. But nothing less either....

Comment: If i saved it, how can i open it again? where should i see it in the database?

Comment: It is not saved somewehere in the database. As I mentioned earlier, it's a separate tool.